# Neo4j: Authentication Failure in browser only, success otherwise

Tags: neo4j

I'm getting an authentication error when trying to connect via the Neo4j Browser:

`The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure. (ID:3F07571939120DB3905D8D08F1A7366A4AC6A49B2AC3F43AFA76A7AEAF221DB3)`

However, our applications can connect and make requests all day through the APIs using the same credentials that we are trying at the browser.

Are there any server configs that I may be missing for this? Here are our versions.

```
Neo4j Version 3.0.1
Browser Version 2.0.0-M04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bolt problem with the versions of Neo4j server and browser that i was running. Having submitted an issue over neo4j's github, they were able to identify this for us:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/280

The recommendation was to disable bolt for the browser, and I was able to connect once again.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to the way your web browser caches web site info. Try clearing the cache (e.g., by refreshing the page).